# Problems with create_function after updating to PHP8

Tags: php, wordpress

Maybe this is ridiculous question. But I am not so strong in PHP. I update PHP at website to PHP8 and have some problems with old theme which is not updated to fit PHP8. In another cases I replaced create_function() with anonymous function() and it worked. But in one place I have code:

```
$this->ext['ev'] = create_function('$v', 'return ev'.'al($v);');
```

actually whole construction looks like:

```
class king{
...
   function __construct() {
   ...
     $this->ext['ev'] = create_function('$v', 'return ev'.'al($v);');
   ...
   }
}
```

and after updating to PHP8 obviously it throws critical error PHP Deprecated.

I tried to modify it like:

```
$this->ext['ev'] = function($v) {
 return ev.al($v);
};
```

in another place it worked. In this case it throws error.
Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: The `.` isn't part of the function in the original code, it's normal string concatenation - `'return ev'.'al($v);'` is just another way to write `'return eval($v);'` Maybe the original author was trying to avoid a scanner detecting that they were using the `eval()` function.

Comment: Yeah, this is kinda sketchy. It seems the only reason this function exists is to hide the fact that it runs externally-provided code.

Comment: Thank you, my friends. Seems it works. It do not throw an error at least. So, really thank you.